# Heap Sort problem

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, heap

I'm working now on heap sort. The codes I have so far has a wrong output. For example I entered 4 3 5 2 1, the first number I entered always position on the last index. The output will be 1 2 3 5 4. Any ideas what is the problem with my codes.

```
    int[] nums = new int[100];
    int SizeNum;
    int x;
    int currentPass;
    int nPass = 1;

    private void ExeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            nPass = 1;
            string[] numsInString = EntNum.Text.Split(' ');   //split values in textbox
            for (int j = 0; j < numsInString.Length; j++)
            {
                nums[j] = int.Parse(numsInString[j]);
            }
            if (SizeNum == numsInString.Length)
            {
                SortArray(currentPass);
                ResultText.AppendText("\n\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public void SortArray(int currentPass)
    {
        int i;
        int temp;
        for (i = (SizeNum / 2) - 1; i >= SizeNum; i--)
            {
                siftDown(i, x, currentPass + 1);
            }

            for (i = SizeNum - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                temp = nums[0];
                nums[0] = nums[i];
                nums[i] = temp;
                siftDown(0, i - 1, currentPass + 1);
                Display(currentPass);
            }
            Display(currentPass); 
        }        

    public void siftDown(int root, int bottom, int currentPass)
    {
        bool done = false;
        int maxChild;
        int temp;

        while ((root * 2 <= bottom) && (!done))
        {
            if (root * 2 == bottom)
                maxChild = root * 2;
            else if (nums[root * 2] > nums[root * 2 + 1])
                maxChild = root * 2;
            else
                maxChild = root * 2 + 1;
            Display(currentPass);
            if (nums[root] < nums[maxChild])
            {
                temp = nums[root];
                nums[root] = nums[maxChild];
                nums[maxChild] = temp;
                root = maxChild;
            }                
            else
            {
                done = true;
            }             
        }
        Display(currentPass);
    }

    public void Display(int currentPass)
    {
        int i;
        String numbers = "";
        ResultText.AppendText("Pass " + nPass + ":    ");
        for (i = 0; i < SizeNum; i++)
        numbers += nums[i].ToString() + " , ";
        ResultText.AppendText(numbers + "\n");
        nPass++;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints on your code and debugging?

Answer (score 1):

One problem is at this line:

```
if (SizeNum == numsInString.Length)
```

As `SizeNum` field is not initialized, its value is the default one, i.e. 0.
Therefore when you insert `"5 4 3 2 1"`, `numsInString.Length` become equal to `5` and then the code in that `if` is not reached.
In fact if you set `SizeNum = numsInString.Length` your code seems to work.

Anyway, as pointed out by other users, if you're using an IDE like visual studio or sharp-develop, you should use the debugger that is really really helpful to find code problems.

Here's an how-to for Visual Studio:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The first for loop of SortArray should be

```
for (i = (SizeNum / 2) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

This is building you heap. You are starting from the second to last layer of children and moving all the way to the top node of the tree.